# AWK command help

Tags: awk

How do I write an awk command that reads through the /etc/passwd file, and prints out just the names of any users who have the /bin/bash program as their default command shell?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
cat /etc/passwd | awk -F ":" '$7=="/bin/bash" { print $1 }'
```

Comment: +1 but useless use of cat! :-) `awk -F: '$7 == "/bin/bash" { print $1 }' /etc/passwd`

Answer (score 3):

Since this is homework, I won't write the program for you (and hopefully no one else does either), but here is what you need to know:

- The default field separator in AWK is whitespace; the field separator in `/etc/passwd` is a colon.  You can change the field separator in AWK via the `FS` variable, or `-F` at the command line.
- In `/etc/passwd/`, the shell is listed in the 7th field.

Well, in the time it took me to write this much, two people have done your homework for you.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

`awk -F: '/\/bin\/bash$/{print $1}' /etc/passwd`

Comment: So /bin/bash is the same as /tmp/attack/bin/bash?

Comment: Good catch.  Checking against the entire field, as Bear did, is a better approach.

Comment: Since you have set delimiter to ":" , why check the entire line for bash? use $7

Comment: @ghostdog74: That's exactly what I was referring to with my reply to Roger.  I didn't edit my answer so as to leave consistency with the comments.

Answer (score 0):

@OP, you can use awk

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=":"}$7~/bash/{print $1}' /etc/passwd
```

the above checks for bash, but does not restrict to /bin/bash. If you definitely need /bin/bash, change it.

OR tell your teacher you want to use just the shell

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS=":" read -r user b c d e f sh h
do
    case "$sh" in
        *bash* ) echo $user;;
    esac
done <"/etc/passwd"
```